# Is it logically possible for a CLI PHP script to update PHP (itself) while running? (On Windows.)

Tags: windows, php

I run Windows 10. On it, I constantly run CLI PHP scripts. My PHP installation dir is `C:\PHP`.

Whenever there is a new version of PHP (stable branch), my scripts detect this, download the new ZIP file from the PHP website, checks the checksum, checks VirusTotal, extract the archive into `C:\PHP-new`, open up WinMerge with the `C:\PHP\php.ini` and `C:\PHP-new\php.ini` files in a diff view, allowing me to make the necessary updates/modifications, and notifies me about this.

Finally, I run a script to safely shut down my CLI PHP system, then delete the `C:\PHP` dir and rename `C:\PHP-new` into `C:\PHP`. Then I start up my system again, and now it's running the new PHP version.

Even though I've automated most of this, it still isn't fully automated. Therefore, I've recently been trying to make it do the last step as well.

Therefore, I had my system signal to all my loop scripts to shut down, and when only the update script is left, I attempted to have it delete the `C:\PHP` dir and rename the `C:\PHP-new`, but this (as expected) did not fully work; it started deleting files but failed as soon as it encountered a DLL which was actively "in use" by the CLI PHP script doing this work. Permission denied, etc.

My question is thus: is there any logical way that my CLI PHP script can do this? Perhaps some special "temporary mode" I can enter, specifically made to allow for this kind of thing?

If it's not possible, then that means that I cannot fully automate the updating of PHP, doesn't it?

Before you tell me about some third-party package manager like "Chocolatey", I don't like such things, for several important reasons. If anything, I would've loved for PHP itself to have the ability to update itself, but I realize that it becomes problematic to say the least due to the configuration file step, which will have to be manual no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not allow you to delete in-use executable images – but allows you to move/rename them.

It should be possible to **rename C:\PHP to C:\PHP-old**, then rename C:\PHP-new into the proper location. Afterwards, spawn a separate "clean up" script using the freshly-installed php.exe and it will be able to delete C:\PHP-old which should be no longer in use.